# Is it possible to change decimation precision of Scope in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, scope, precision, simulink

I'm saving the data of the scope while simulating into the workspace. I've seen that the data has four decimal places, e.g. 1.4617. Now in my case I need a higher precision. Is it possibly to adjust the data? Since I need a script to build my model it would be the easiest way. Alternatively I would use the "toWorkspace"-block.

Comment: Internal default precision is double. Try 'format long'  to see more digits.

Comment: To add to what @Nras said, the data may only be *displayed* with 4 digits, but it is *stored* with double precision. As suggested, change the format of the display to see more digits. The To Workspace block stores data with double precision as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments:

Matlab and Simulink do not usually calculate with 4 digits of precision, but many more. (It uses double precision, which typically means about 14 decimals in practice).

However, the 4 digits are what is shown by default.

For showing more, try `format long`, just don't worry about the lack of shown digits reducing the accuracy of your calculations.